# Find unadded files in Team Foundation Server

Tags: version-control, tfs

We're using team foundation server for our source control. I frequently put files into my project (under source control) and forget to "add" them as far as TFS is concerned. There are also cases where TFS doesn't pick up new files (copy and paste a file in your project).

Is there a way I can list all of the files that have not been marked as "add" so that I can verify that all of the intended check-ins take place?

This is driving me crazy! We don't have continuous integration set up yet for this project, and I keep missing files. I don't find out until someone asks me where the file in.

In Subversion, this was dead simple.

I know one solution is to checkout a second copy, but that's not really an optimal workaround.

Comment: NINE YEARS later and this is a bigger problem than ever for me :-(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might want to make sure you have the latest version of the TFS client installed ([VS 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9e40a5b6-da41-43a2-a06d-3cee196bfe3d)) as that makes it much easier to work with files.  Also, take a look at the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs2008/bb980963.aspx) - especially the tfpt online command.

The tfpt command line has a bunch of handy TFS utilities.  Once you install the TFS power tools, type "tfpt help" at a Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt to get a list.  If you do "tfpt online /r" in the root of your solution it will detect the files that are writeable in your local file system and pend adds or edits for them.  You might want to limit the command so that it only looks for source files - "tfpt online /r *.cs" for example.

Comment: Taking solution offline then back online might do similar trick.

Answer (score 69):

Go to Source Control Explorer, right click on the folder you are interested in and choose compare.

This will show both files that are not added and also files that have been modified without checking out first.

This solution does not require Power Tools

Comment: Except if you have hundreds of files scattered throughout your tree, you can't easily select them all for adding.

Comment: Be sure to check the 'Show items that exist only in target path' and you can then see just local files that are missing. For newer .NET Core projects there will be perhaps hundreds of files in node_modules that shouldn't be checked in so this view can get quite slow.

Answer (score 12):

Yes there is.  Navigate to Source Control Explorer.  Click on the project you're interested in.  Click the "Add Items to Folder" button.  It is two over from the refresh button.  This will give you a list of all files that are in the folder but not added to source control.

Comment: That does work, but it's not recursive. Navigating through the entire folder structure can be very difficult.

Comment: probably the next best thing is to write code for this.  TFS has a full managed set of code for talking to TFS so you should be trivial to write code to recursively check each folder and TFS for files not added.

Comment: Using 'tfpt online', as in the accepted answer, is much easier than writing your own code against the TFS API (in case anybody skips over the accepted answer for some reason :p )

Comment: How is this different from [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483977/find-unadded-files-in-team-foundation-server/4804556#4804556) ?

Comment: For recursive folders, but in the first step, when the add files dialog is displayed, you must select all folders with the mouse. I tested and it works.

Answer (score 4):

In VS 2015 this helped me to add file to the Version Control

1. Open "Add Items to Folder..." Context menu item in Source Control Explorer
2. Add necessary files

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

'Inspired' by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660259/how-to-browse-and-view-files-stored-in-a-team-foundation-server-without-using-vis/1955573#1955573)

The [TFS Power Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15836)
) now have Windows Shell Extensions, so you manipulate source control files using only Windows Explorer.

The option you're after is Compare with workspace version - this works recursively too, and allows one to selectively add/delete, etc. (yes, `tf.exe` will probably have an equivalent)

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/bharry/WindowsLiveWriter/PreviewofthenextTFSPowerToolsrelease_72E3/image_thumb_11.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/bharry/WindowsLiveWriter/PreviewofthenextTFSPowerToolsrelease_72E3/image_20.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio, you can right-click a folder in the Solution Explorer and choose `Add > Existing item`. Unfortunately, the resulting "add file dialog" doesn't automatically scope to the folder you clicked.

However, there is also a button in Solution Explorer called "Show all files". After clicking this, files not included in the project will appear and get an "include in project" context menu item. Including them will usually put them in TFS's "Pending changes" list as "added" automatically.

[image]

([Source](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-files-created-outside-of-Visual-Studio-not-show-up-in-the-Solution-Explorer-unless-you-add-them-manually).)

Answer (score 1):

Migrate to git, like Microsoft is doing :)

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2017, this is still a problem, but easily repaired:
Navigate to :  SOLUTION EXPLORER
second button to right of REFRESH circular arrow is: SHOW ALL FILES
Click that

All your files will appear faded out, but visible. Right click on each one and select "INCLUDE in PROJECT"

when your all done, snail Mail a letter of complaint to Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the following Powershell script would spit out the files that are not yet added:

```
[hashtable] $lps = [hashtable]::new()

tf info . -recursive | findstr /r /c:"^  Local path :" | foreach-object {
    $lp = $_ -replace '^  Local path : ', ''
    if ($lp) {
        $lps[$lp.toLower()] = $null
    }
}

get-childItem -recurse | foreach-object {
    if (-not $lps.ContainsKey($_.fullName.toLower())) {
       (resolve-path -relative $_.fullName).toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In TFS Source Control Explorer
Right Click root folder which may somwewhere in a sub folder have UN-ADDED files
Choose Compare
Check options

- show items that exist only in target path
- show items that are different

Then the diff results will show the missing files.