# How to browse and view files stored in a Team Foundation Server without using Visual Studio

Tags: tfs

I'm looking for a tool to browse and view files stored within a Team Foundation Server without using Visual Studio. As I'm doing most development on a virtual machine, it's very annoying to wake it up only to have a look on a certain file.

So is there a way to browse a TFS without Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use emacs and [the TFS module for it](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/tfs.el).
A couple keystrokes retrieves a file from the server.

The tfs mode is built on [tf.exe, the team foundation command-line client powertool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e(VS.80).aspx).

Of course, you could use tf.exe by itself, or with an alternative editor, like notepad++.

Answer (score 10):

The TFS Power Tools now have Windows Shell Extensions, so you manipulate source control files using only Windows explorer. Your solution could be to just keep a working copy of the solution and then you do whatever manipulations you need to using Windows Explorer.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBD14EEA-781F-45A1-8C46-9F6BA2F68BF0&displaylang=en

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/bharry/WindowsLiveWriter/PreviewofthenextTFSPowerToolsrelease_72E3/image_thumb_11.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/bharry/WindowsLiveWriter/PreviewofthenextTFSPowerToolsrelease_72E3/image_20.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TFS Web Access (most likely at your tfs server, http, port 8090 (http://server:8090/)

Comment: anything you need to set up to access TFS by web? It does not work for our TFS :(