# TFS get latest version with new files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm having problems with TFS when adding new files or folders to my solution.

When any other people in the team try to "get latest" it updates every changed file but it doesn't download the new added files!!

If we go to the Source Control explorer, the new files appear as "not downloaded"... and if we force it to download, then we have to include the file in the project in his machine too.

I can't believe this is the normal behavior for TFS (I think this is basic) so I assume we are doing something wrong... Any idea of what's happening??

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Are you issuing the Get Latest from **Solution** Explorer or **Source Control** Explorer? Or command line?

Comment: What TFS version are you using?

Comment: AakashM I'm usinng Solution Explorer usually. Then I've to use source control explorer to force download.

pantelif I'm using TFS 2010.

Comment: I find that files created by others do get downloaded.  But they are not included in the local project.  `Show All Files` reveals their presence.  One can manually include them as a subsequent operation.  But its perplexing that they're not included automatically.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you also checked in the project file to which the added files are related?  In Solution Explorer these files will only be available if they are also in the local project file.  Also check if the user attempting to download has the project file checked out already.

Update:
From within Solution Explorer you'll only get what's required for the referenced files in the .proj file.  For Source Control Explorer yes it should get those files if you've never downloaded them before.  Best way to be sure is rather than just do Get Latest (which tries to sync what it understands server side about your local workspace with the server) do a Get Specific Version -> Latest Version.  This way you can "force" download of all project files irrespective of existing workspace status.

Comment: I'll check this but I think we are doing it already. Anyway I think files should be downloaded shouldn't them?

Answer (score 9):

The hint above did not help in my scenario.
What did do the trick was to check out an old version (with the two overwrite-checkboxes) and get the latest version afterwards (also with the two overwrite-checkboxes).

This is a huge bug in TFS IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. My co-worker created a new file (with content, not just an empty file). He did a check-in, and everything went well on his end. But the file never got downloaded to my project. I could go into Source control explorer and navigate to the file in question, then do a "get latest version" or "get specific version" on it, but it still didn't appear in my project.

Then my co-worker did some cosmetic changes to the file and did another commit. This time, when I did a simple "get latest version" on the whole project, the file downloaded without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the most voted answer in this thread. This should be the nearest to what you are looking for

[Find unadded files in Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483977/find-unadded-files-in-team-foundation-server)