# Third party dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have the following dir. struct

```
$/
 TeamProj1/
     Solution1/
         <Solution and files etc>
  TeamProj2/
     Libs/
       LibSolution1/
         <solution and files etc>
     External/
      ThirdParty.dll
```

Solution1 has a project reference to LibSolution1, and has an assembly reference to ThirdParty.dll.

When I do a fresh check out of Solution1 via File->Open from source control TFS correctly checks out the LibSolution1 files, but not the third party dll.
If I manually check out the third party dll everything builds.

How do I force TFS to check out the correct third party dll files?
I can think of two possible methods but don't particularly like either.
1) I could add a libs folder to Solution1 and add the dll there. Then the dll will be checked out when solution1 is checked out. I don't like this method though because there are solutions in addition to Solution1 that will use the third party assembly, and I want to maintain only a single copy of the file.

2) I could create a "dummy" ThirdParty project/solution and add the files to that solution, then add the dummy project to solution1 solution. Then when I check out solution1, it would see the dummy project and check it out along with all the associated files (being the third party dlls)... but that seems unnecessarily complex.

Isn't there a way I can instruct TFS to simply check out the required file?

Comment: Is it correct that with check-out you actually mean 'get-latest'? Or does the thirdparty.dll needs to be writeable?

Comment: Can you not just open Source Control Explorer and do a Get Latest there instead?  For why this doesn't work in solution explorer, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203441/tfs-get-latest-version-with-new-files and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634401/is-there-a-way-to-make-get-latest-in-tfs-behave-like-get-specific-version-of-the

Comment: @rene: Third party .dll does not need to be writeable. 'get-latest' would most likly work as well.

Comment: @Edward: I can open Source Control Explorer and Manually get latest of the file, However, I want the file to be gotten automatically when freshly opening via open from source control. I do not want to have to do anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution here is a variation of your option 1 but without having to maintain multiple copies of the DLL's.

Add a new folder to your Solution1 (say Third_Party_DLL). Right CLick the folder -> Add existing item and instead of adding the DLL's physically here (create a link to these third party DLL's from the location where you have saved it). Now after adding the DLL links in the folder, add reference to the DLL's in your project from this folder (Third_party_Dll).

Now when you are getting the latest of the solution file, it should get your DLL's too. I havent tried this out myself for Dll's but have done this for maintaining a single copy of the AssemblyVersion file and it worked well. Try and let me know.

[Add Vs Add Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234)