# Get Latest misses new code in Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

This question is asking, "Am I doing something wrong," or "Is this a failure in VS2010 and TFS?"

Whenever I open Visual Studio 2010, I habitually do a "GetLatest" from TFS, and often have it overwrite my local files whether they are updated or not just to be safe.  I want to make sure that any code I publish has the latest updates from other team members.  Then we all check in our changes as soon as possible in order to stay in sync, as the entire team uses this practice.

What we are finding is that when NEW code is checked in (e.g. a new aspx with code-behind) doing a GetLatest will NOT grab the new files.  All we get are updates to files that already exist in our local working directory.  Are we doing something wrong?  Is there a checkbox we need to tick somewhere to force VS 2010 to get files that are new rather than just update existing changes?

Comment: Is the path where the files exist mapped in your workspace?

Comment: Yes. The folder already exists and has other files in it.

Comment: May have found the solution here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203441/tfs-get-latest-version-with-new-files?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make Get Latest in TFS behave like Get Specific Version of the latest checkin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634401/is-there-a-way-to-make-get-latest-in-tfs-behave-like-get-specific-version-of-the)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common and is the result of your local workspace getting out of sync. If it happens a lot you should delete the local TFS cache. That's in %profile%\local\Microsoft\teamfoundation*.

The best way to completely eradicate the issue is to upgrade to a newer version. This was resolved with Local Workspaces in 2012 and with Git in 2013. Its pretty strate forward to upgrade.