# Source Control Explorer does not retrieve newly checked in files

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I have recently created a new Project and  Checked into our Development branch(TFS) from visual studio but when my team mates tried to get the latest version or map the branch to their local , the newly added project does not appear .

But everybody is able to see the folder containing the new project in the Source controller explorer but not in Solution Explorer

Issue is , the newly added project doesn't appear , appreciate your help .

Comment: Did you commit the solution file (and did you add the project to the solution?)

Comment: Yes , Added and Committed from Solution file

Comment: Is the solution file shown in your commit as one of the files that changed? Is the new project file available on the disk when your teammembers map the branch in their workspace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find unadded files in Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483977/find-unadded-files-in-team-foundation-server)

Comment: yes rene , its available in the workspace but not in solution explorer when they take the latest code

Comment: Make sure to save your solution file, touch it and commit it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Jim, according to your description, the project was not added to the solution. So you can see the project file in source control explorer but cannot display in Solution Explorer.

You have to add the project to the solution. In **Solution Explorer** , Right-click on the solution >> **Add** >> **Existing Prject** >> Select the project to add, then check in the changes.

If that still not work, just try to create a new project from Solution Explorer and check in the changes: Right-click on the solution >> **Add** >> **New Prject**

Thus, the project will be retrieved with the solution.

[image]

Comment: Hi ,I have followed the same procedure when i created the project and the same has been checked in , for now my work around is to manually add the project into solution from source controller explorer as get latest is not getting the project into solution

Comment: Again - that's exactly what we're telling you to do. That's how it's done. If we've answered your question, upvotes are appreciated.

Comment: Hi Andy, I have identified the solution and added below

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the project to the solution. Right-click on the solution, and add the project.

Comment: Hi ,I have followed the same procedure when i created the project and the same has been checked in , for now my work around is to manually add the project into solution from source controller explorer .

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. If either of us have answered your question, please vote. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jim , I have identified the solution and added below