# Can't see package in solution restored TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, ssis, source-control-explorer

I am working with TFS control source on visual studio, my problem is that I can't find in the solution VS a package that I created before, I am sure that I check in pended changes when I create it; I restored the last version after that.
  Now I can see it in the server, also in the workspace folder but not in the solution on VS.

Package in tfs workspace folder:

[image]

Package not existing in the solution on VS:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't add the files/Package to the solution or even you didn't create a solution.

If you have created a solution, then just need to add the files to that solution:

Open the solution --> 
Navigate to `Solution Explorer` --> 
Right click the solution --> `Add` --> `Existing item...` --> Select the files/package to add them

If no solution there, then just create a solution and follow above steps to add the files to the new solution...

Reference another similar thread : [Source Control Explorer does not retrieve newly checked in files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897673/source-control-explorer-does-not-retrieve-newly-checked-in-files/45911851#45911851)

[image]