# Get latest version - files missing in TFS but available in local folder

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, ssis

I am working with `ssis` packages with TFS. I checked-in after finishing my work. My teammate had to continue his work, so he get the latest version but he didn't find all the files on the server version but when checking in our local folders we can find them. So we tried to import them like following :

I need to import `Employee.dtsx`, it is imported as Employee 1.dtsx and when I try to rename to `Employee 1.dtsx`, I get this following message :

> 'C:\XXX\Employee.dtsx' already exists in this project.

Comment: While not exactly a duplicate, I'm pretty sure you'll find some useful information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483977/find-unadded-files-in-team-foundation-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try opening the project file (.dtproj) and check whether the package is listed there, and manually add it in if the package does not exist in project file. You can refer to [this discussion](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/tfs-ssis-get-latest-version-not-showing-all-dtsx-files-solution-explorer).

You can find the details steps to [add Files to Source Control--Team Foundation Server](https://help.madcapsoftware.com/flare2017r2/Content/Source-Control/Shared/TFS/Adding-Files-to-Source-Control-tfs.htm) in the blog. Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Hi @xXx Did you try out the solutions in above link. Did it work out?